# DataInputStream deprecated readLine() method

Tags: java, user-input, readline, datainputstream

I am on java 6. Using `DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);` to read user input. When the readLine() is deprecated. What is the work around for reading user value?

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
int num;
try
{
  num = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()); //this works

  num = Integer.parseInt(in);  //just in doesnt work.
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

please explain as it should when the readLine() is deprecated.

Comment: Please include a compilable test case (or a failing test case with the applicable error) next time.

Comment: Test case?  We're talking deprecation.  You put the code above into an editor and it turns the line yellow and say "readLine is deprecated".  No one needs a test case to be told a java method is deprecated.   Here's the applicable warning:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`InputStream` is fundamentally a binary construct. If you want to read *text* data (e.g. from the console) you should use a `Reader` of some description. To convert an `InputStream` into a `Reader`, use `InputStreamReader`. Then create a `BufferedReader` around the `Reader`, and you can read a line using `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

More alternatives:

- Use a [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) built round `System.in`, and call `Scanner.nextLine`
- Use a [`Console`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) (obtained from `System.console()`) and call `Console.readLine`

Answer (score 30):

Deprecation and the alternatives is usually already explicitly explained in the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/). So it would be the first place to look for the answer. For `DataInputStream` you can find it [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html). The `readLine()` method is [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29). Here's an extract of relevance:

> **Deprecated**. This method does not properly convert bytes to characters. As of JDK 1.1, the preferred way to read lines of text is via the `BufferedReader.readLine()` method. Programs that use the `DataInputStream` class to read lines can be converted to use the `BufferedReader` class by replacing code of the form:
>
> ```
>     DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(in);
> ```
>
> with:
>
> ```
>     BufferedReader d
>          = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
> ```

The character encoding can then be explicitly specified in the constructor of `InputStreamReader`.

The [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) which was introduced since Java 1.5 is also a good (and modern) alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The below doesn't work,

```
num = Integer.parseInt(in);
```

Instead you should use:

```
num = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
```

`readLine()` will read an input of line until line break.

Answer (score 0):

calling **readLine** command in scala returns "warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details" message.

You can handle this warning as illustrated below

```
val hadoopConfig = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
val hdfs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
val destinationFile = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(s"hdfs://...")
val outFile = hdfs.open(destinationFile)

val wholeStream = Array.fill[Byte](outFile.available)(0)
outFile.readFully(wholeStream,0,outFile.available)
return new String(wholeStream)
```