# Setting Resources folder using Spring

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jdbc, filenotfoundexception

I am using Spring MVC + JDBC to make a web-app, and i've created a DAO Class to handle queries. My problem is this: I have this really big query, and I would like to keep it in a .txt file and read the query inside the DAO, but I keep getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. Where should I put my .txt with my queries?
I've tried to store it in the same class as the DAO, but it didn`t work.

I`m a complete beginner when it comes to use Spring MVC, and I have installed the SprigSource Tool Suite, so everything is pre-configured.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Thank you!

Cesar Vargas

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBNpV.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXu1K.png

Comment: You really should tell us about the details, e.g. where did you place the file, how does the relevant part of your code look like?

Comment: Well, i've tried to store the file in the same folder as the DAO. I erased all the bad code, so Ill have to do it again, then ill post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("queriesCountJava.txt");`

which looks for the file on the classpath.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. But i have a doubt: is there any other way to read data different than `.readLine()` method? In Eclipse, it says it`s deprecated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611387/datainputstream-deprecated-readline-method