# Android/Java Java socket oputput or input stream is null

Tags: java, android, sockets

I making android applicaton and i have java.lang.NullPointerException with this code. Java server is on the comuter. Thanks for help.

```
try {
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Socket socket;
                socket = new Socket("192.168.0.179", 5450);
                os = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                in = is.readLine().trim();

                if(in == "hello") {
                    os.print(edit.getText().toString());
                    os.flush();
                    Log.d("LoL", in);
                    Log.d("LoL", edit.getText().toString());
                    in = is.readLine().trim();
                    edit.setText(in);
                    os.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("LoL",e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of your exception

Comment: Post the stactrace ad highlight the line that is causing the exception please. Is `edit == null`? Is `ok == null`?

Comment: "Java server is on the computer." - sounds good enough :D

Comment: There is precisely zero evidence here that a socket input or output stream is null. -1

Answer (score 1):

The `in == "hello"` expression will always return false, because you'll want to compare the *contents* of the strings `in` and `"hello"`; that expression checks that they are the same object, and that will never happen. For any non-primitive type like strings, we should write `"hello".equals(in)`. (you may also write `in.equals("hello")` but the latter form prevents another possible NullPointerException)

Since that expression will always return false, the if block will never execute. Therefore, the NPE may happen only in two places:

- in `ok.setOnClickListener`: if the ok variable is null, e.g. is not initialized, calling any method on it will lead to NPE;
- in `in = is.readLine().trim();`: if the InputStream is empty (e.g. got no data or EOF from the server) `is.readLine()` will return null, and calling `trim()` on a null object will lead to NPE.

BTW, `InputStream.readLine()` is deprecated, better use `BufferedReader` instead. That's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5611387/327648).

Comment: Error still happen but thanks.